# How to get values from a inner function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

HI HAVE A SIMPLE FUNCTION WHICH TAKE A NUMBER AND VERIFY IT

```
var verifyNumber =(phoneNumber)=>{
//Number Verification 
cb.validatePhone(phoneNumber,'sms',(err,data)=>{
if(err){
    console.log(`You got an error `);
}
console,log('Code send');
return data 
})
}

verifyNumber('***********');
```

but the problem is that i want the response which the cb.validatePhone() is given back which is in the 2nd param (data)

and when i return it gave me "undefined" :( 
 so you can a get the data which is a Object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to return data from an async operation.

Here's an example using a callback:

```
function verifyNumber(phoneNumber, callback) {
  try {
    cb.validatePhone(phoneNumber, 'sms', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw new Error('You got an error');
      callback(data); 
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

verifyNumber('***********', (data) => console.log(data));
```

Here's one using a [`promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```js
function verifyNumber(phoneNumber) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      cb.validatePhone(phoneNumber, 'sms', (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw new Error('You got an error');
        resolve(data);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
}

verifyNumber('***********').then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thank You some much it worked as you showed 
i think  i really need to learn Promise

Comment: I added an example with a callback too so you can see the differences.